# What punch down tool should I use on this ethernet jack?

Tags: switches, cables, networking, router

As you can tell this does not have the vertical lines like a regular keystone jack. So i was wondering what punch down tool should i use? ...also what are these called?
[image: click here to view the image.]

Comment: A sledgehammer? Those look a bit like some where the "punch tool" is built into the cover.

Comment: A Krone tool? May be other brand names too.

Comment: I've always know them as Krone, generic term is IDC (Insulation Displacement Connector).

Comment: Does a standard .110 punchdown not work? I have jacks like that, and just use my normal punchdown too.

Comment: I do use OLFA knife, turned arround.

Answer (score 1):

This type of connector usually cuts the insulation by itself when you push the cover in place.

However, I've had non consistent results depending on whether the core of the conductors was solid or stranded. In some cases I ended up peeling the core before inserting.